# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_distribution_strategy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, attributeerror

I'm trying to train a UNet, but for some reason I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-54-b56497e81356>", line 1, in <module>
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=opt.learning_rate), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])

  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\gpuconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 537, in compile
    with self.distribute_strategy.scope():

  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\gpuconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 682, in distribute_strategy
    return self._distribution_strategy or ds_context.get_strategy()

AttributeError: 'UNet' object has no attribute '_distribution_strategy'
```

I already looked for multiple answers of which one was replacing `keras` into `tf.keras`, but the error still arises. Another anwer was that it had to do with TensorBoard, so I removed the Tensorboard callback, but that also didn't fix it.

This is my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class UNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, img_shape=(256,256,256), num_class=1):
        print ('build UNet ...')
        
        self.img_shape = img_shape+(1,)
        self.num_class = num_class

    def get_crop_shape(self, target, refer):
        # depth, the 4th dimension
        cd = (target.get_shape()[3] - refer.get_shape()[3])
        assert (cd >= 0)
        if cd % 2 != 0:
            cd1, cd2 = int(cd//2), int(cd//2) + 1
        else:
            cd1, cd2 = int(cd//2), int(cd//2)
        # width, the 3rd dimension
        cw = (target.get_shape()[2] - refer.get_shape()[2])
        assert (cw >= 0)
        if cw % 2 != 0:
            cw1, cw2 = int(cw//2), int(cw//2) + 1
        else:
            cw1, cw2 = int(cw//2), int(cw//2)
        # height, the 2nd dimension
        ch = (target.get_shape()[1] - refer.get_shape()[1])
        assert (ch >= 0)
        if ch % 2 != 0:
            ch1, ch2 = int(ch//2), int(ch//2) + 1
        else:
            ch1, ch2 = int(ch//2), int(ch//2)
    
        return (ch1, ch2), (cw1, cw2), (cd1, cd2)
    
    def __call__(self, inputs):
        
        concat_axis = 4
        
        conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_1')(inputs)
        conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
        pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv1)
        conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
        conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
        
        up_conv1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2))(conv2)
        ch, cw, cd = self.get_crop_shape(conv1, up_conv1)
        crop_conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Cropping3D(cropping=(ch,cw,cd))(conv1)
        up1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([up_conv1, crop_conv1], axis=concat_axis)
        conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)
        conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(8, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
        
        ch, cw, cd = self.get_crop_shape(inputs, conv3)
        conv3 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding3D(padding=((ch[0], ch[1]), (cw[0], cw[1]), (cd[0], cd[1])))(conv3)
        conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(self.num_class, (1, 1, 1), activation="sigmoid")(conv3)
        
        return conv4
```

And this is how I'm trying to train it:

```
# Initialize the model
model = UNet(img_shape=opt.img_shape, num_class=opt.num_class)
    
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=opt.learning_rate), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
    
callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(opt.checkpoint_path, "UNet.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.3f}.hdf5")),
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=opt.log_dir, histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_images=True, update_freq='epoch')
    ]
                                        
# Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch.
model.fit(trainDataset, epochs=opt.epoch, validation_data=testDataset, callbacks=callbacks)
```

I'm not using a distribution strategy. I use python version 3.7.9 and tensorflow version 2.3.0.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, fortunately.
I forgot to call the superclass of the tensorflow keras model; I just had to add `super(MyModel, self).__init__()` to my `__init__()` function.

So my model looks like this now:

```
class UNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, img_shape=(256,256,256), num_class=1):
        super(UNet, self).__init__()
        print ('build UNet ...')
        
        self.img_shape = img_shape
        self.num_class = num_class
    
    ...
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install -q tensorflow==2.2
!pip install -q keras==2.3.1
```

can definitely solve this ,, enjoy;)